# Gcm c2d permission in different build variants

Tags: android

After different solution like this nothing works out.

But I am signing different flavours with different Keystore so this is not working.

Any clues?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/> This also didn't worked as I am signing with different keystores.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own experience:

First of all, Edit your main AndroidManifest.xml, using ${applicationId} as below:

```
<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Since you use the same GCMIntentService class for different build variants.Then, create your own GCMBroadcastReceiver by overriding.

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;

public class MyGCMBroadcastReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context)
    {
        return "com.example.GCMIntentService";
        //you may replace with your own GCMIntentService path.
    }
}
```

Finally, edit the receiver tag at AndroidManifest.xml, as below:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.MyGCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I hope it helps you, thanks.